# Open a new opera window from the command line in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, browser, window, opera

My opera version is `33.0.1990.43` running on ubuntu.
I would like to open a new opera window through the command line (which is executed via a keyboard shortcut).

I have tried to run different variations of `opera --newwindow` (taken from http://www.opera.com/docs/switches/) with 1 dash or two dashes, etc. It doesn't seem to be an available option. I have looked through the settings and nothing.

`opera --help` gives me the following:

```
$ opera --help                                                                                            [15:33:20]
Opera 33.0.1990.43 Stable        
Features available through command-line switches:
    --with-feature:submodule-native-theme-alt [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:accessible_panes [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:addons-detailed-errors [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:autoupdate-notifications [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:bookmarks-api-on-speed-dial [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:browser-engine-statistics [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:bundle-downloads [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:bundle-history [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:bundled-themes-on-disk [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:certificate-transparency [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:default-browser-prompt-in-start-page [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:disable-npapi [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:drag-and-drop-downloads [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:encrypted-media-extensions [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:extended-feature-stats [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:extended-lazy-session-loading [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:extension-content-verification [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:extension-desktop-capture-api [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:forced-default-browser-prompt [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:hidpi-speed-dial-tiles [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:hi-resolution-thumbnails [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:intel-realsense-support [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:invalidations-webui [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:linux-libnotify-toasts [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:mac-toolbar-redesign [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:new-tabs-model [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:npapi-removal-notification [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:other-speed-dials-cleaner [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:enable-platform-accelerated-video-decoding [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:proprietary-codecs-support-for-web-audio-api [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:restore-contenteditables-state [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:share-button-visibility [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:show-cancel-download-button [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:show-domain-when-entering-fullscreen [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:show-midi-permission-badge [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:startup-improvements [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:sync-passwords [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:tab-hibernation [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:trees-in-bookmarks [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:use-turbo2 [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:vibrancy-in-window-frame [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:video-theme [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:warn-for-unknown-root [Enabled by default: false]
    --with-feature:bookmark-thumbnails-direct-upload [Enabled by default: true]
    --with-feature:surf-easy-promotion [Enabled by default: true]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
--new-window
```

The first line in the document of the link you provided specifies this :

> This document was last updated for Opera 11.61

Comment: Now if only you could get opera to render fonts properly...

Comment: Chrome kept crashing, so opera was the next best choice for me.

Comment: This also works for windows.

Comment: FWIW other switches can be found at http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ because now Opera is based on Chromium.